# How to read from a text file using VBScript?

Tags: windows, scripting, vbscript

I am looking to see a simple way to read from and write to a text file using VBScript.

I think this is an acceptable method for writing to a file.

```
 Dim f, 
 Dim fso

 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set f = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\test.txt", True, True)

 f.WriteLine("Data to Add to file.")
 f.Close
```

However, I would like to know how to read from a file in a similar fashion.

Comment: I don't understand.  Isn't that what you just did, except you're not using the read methods?

Comment: Yes, but that will only work for one line.

Comment: So use the ReadAll method instead

Comment: `WriteLine` writes one line. `ReadLine` reads one line. `ReadAll` to read whole file (or `Read(fileObj.Size)`), `Write` to write all contents.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use first the method [`OpenTextFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/opentextfile-method), and then...

either read the file at once with the method [`ReadAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/readall-method):

```
Const ForReading = 1
Dim file, content
Dim fso

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set file = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\test.txt", ForReading)
content = file.ReadAll
```

or line by line with the method [`ReadLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/readline-method):

```
Const ForReading = 1
Dim dict, file, row, line

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set file = fso.OpenTextFile ("c:\test.txt", ForReading)
row = 0
Do Until file.AtEndOfStream
  line = file.Readline
  dict.Add row, line
  row = row + 1
Loop

file.Close

'Loop over it
For Each line in dict.Items
  WScript.Echo line
Next
```

Comment: An anonymous user has [suggested some changes](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12118610) to your code. It seems like a valid point, but I don't know for sure. Perhaps you might wish to consider it.

Comment: @NisseEngström I don't see why adding the format -1 (Unicode) as argument to OpenTextFile would answer better the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim obj : Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim outFile : Set outFile = obj.CreateTextFile("in.txt")
Dim inFile: Set inFile = obj.OpenTextFile("out.txt")

' Read file
Dim strRetVal : strRetVal = inFile.ReadAll
inFile.Close

' Write file
outFile.write (strRetVal)
outFile.Close
```