# Editing Emailer Script to Read Addresses From a File

Tags: email, vbscript

How can I get the script to load email addresses one at a time from a text file instead of entering an email in manually?

I keep getting an error that says

> line 6
>   object required:”
>   code 800A01A8

What am I doing wrong?

```
Dim fso

Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objEmail.From = "admin1@fabrikam.com"
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set file = fso.OpenTextFile ("C:\e.txt", 1)
row = 0
Do Until file.AtEndOfStream
  line = file.Readline
  dict.Add row, line
  row = row + 1
  objEmail.To = file
  objEmail.Subject = "Test Email 2"
  objEmail.Textbody = "This Is A Test Message"
  objEmail.AddAttachment "C:\test.txt"
  objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
  objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "127.0.0.1"
  objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
  objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update
  objEmail.Send
Loop
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `objEmail.AddAttachment "c:\windows\win.ini"` see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526914(v=exchg.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks the attachment is now working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read from a text file using VBScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854975/how-to-read-from-a-text-file-using-vbscript)

Comment: Thanks I have tried that but I was unable to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

In your line 6:

```
Set file = fso.OpenTextFile ("C:\e.txt", 1)
```

`fso` is empty/undefined. You need a

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

before.

Your

```
objEmail.To = file
```

probably should be

```
objEmail.To = line
```

Comment: Thank You that’s fixed the problem.