# BAT FILE / Picking up CSV file names and use then in EXCEL Report

Tags: excel, csv, batch-file, cmd, vbscript

I would like to produce report (which currently working fine with 1 exception), need to add all **.CSV** file names to report and I'm stuck with it.

Currently all what I have managed to do is :

- Create bat file which pick up variables from command line by using %1 %2 and so on.
- Then I create a VB Script which picks up variables from BAT file (+ some other things) and generate report in excel
- Working perfectly, but I could not find the way of pick .csv file names and paste them to the same report

What I have:

```
call n:\xx\variables.bat %1 %2 %3 %4
cscript.exe "%vbs%" "%Sample1%" "Sample2" "*.csv"
```

In the bit where says "*.csv" I need to have CSV file name(s), so I can use this variable(s) to place it to Excel by using VBS.

Visual interpretation about what I'm looking for:

```
----------------------------------------------------
-                                                  -
-                                                  -
-                   HERE MY REPORT                 -
-                                                  -
----------------------------------------------------

- CSV FilesPath/FileName1
- CSV FilesPath/FileName2
- CSV FilesPath/FileName3
- CSV FilesPath/FileName4
```

**CSV:**

- CSV Files are always different
- Monday 3, Tuesday-Friday I receive only 1 file
- Very rare I have more than 3
- CSV files located in the same folder as everything else for this job

**EXTRA:**

I found this topic:
[How to read from a text file using VBScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854975/how-to-read-from-a-text-file-using-vbscript)

My be if create a list which will contain all necessary file name, then it will be a way of picked up this list and use as variable in VBS???...

**EXACT SOLUTION:** (Adapted version of AVB but for multiple files)

```
addCell = 6
for each myFile in fso.GetFolder(var1).Files
if fso.GetExtensionName(myFile) = "csv" then
    ws.Cells(addCell,1).Value = myFile.Path ' or do anything else
    addCell=addCell+1
end if
next
```

Comment: Why is it tagged with `excel-vba`?

Comment: Made assumption that this can be done in excel-vba (if this is impossible, then I will remove this tag)

Comment: Do you just want to pick up all of the `.csv` files in this directory and assemble a command line to be passed to your `vba`?

Comment: Yes. All what I need is to list all CSV files with their paths in the excel report.

Comment: so you need to list all .csv files from certain folder inside your script?

Comment: @abv If you talking about the out, I need to list all csv files from the job folder(where all files are) , take this information and insert it to excel file (report). I'm looking for any work around, If It will possible to list all .CSV files inside VBS script as variables, that will be perfect as I know what to do next.

Comment: @Magoo Have update the question, my be this is sort of solution? I just can't make it works.

Comment: We need to pin down where these files are and which files you want to list. Are the required full filenames stored in a file, or do you want to pick up the filenames from a particular directory, or a directory and its subdirectories? And if you want to pick the names from a directory, do you want to also create a file of the filenames found?

Comment: @Magoo if you will look for AVB solution, this is what I was looking for. But his solution does work only if i have 1 file, but I need to expand it to make it work for 2+, which will list them one after another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way to list all csv files from folder:

```
dim FSO, myFile
const myFolder = "your path here"
set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")

for each myFile in FSO.GetFolder(myFolder).Files
    if FSO.GetExtensionName(myFile) = "csv" then
        MsgBox(myFile.Path) ' or do anything else
    end if
next
```

this code, almost unchanged will work in VBA as well (if you use it there avoid late binding)

Comment: ws.Cells(1,1).Value = var2   | --- This is the way I inserting values to excel report. what will be the way of replacing??  "ws.Cells(1,1).Value =myFile.Path"   ???

Comment: Tested, solution  does work, but what should I do, if I have 2 or more files? Somehow like this "ws.Cells(1(+1),1).Value =myFile.Path" that every next file will be inserted in the next line down.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution.

Comment: i was away fo a while, but I see further help is not needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your need, so here's some guesswork:

```
call n:\xx\variables.bat %1 %2 %3 %4
cscript.exe "%vbs%" "%Sample1%" "Sample2" %*
```

The `%*` means *take all parameters*.

Comment: I do not need all parameters, I need only paths(with files names) for CSV files from the folder. which I can use to insert this paths to EXCEL report. May be there is other work around it, I just assumed that this can be done with the way I explained in my question.