# Error 800A03EE in my VB script while running through command prompt

Tags: vbscript, outlook, office365

I am running through command prompt on Windows and I am getting the alert at 24th line and 34th char

Code sample are as follows:

```
Sub CatchMe()

      Dim outobj, mailobj
      Dim strFileText
      Dim objFileToRead

      Set outobj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
      Set mailobj = outobj.CreateItem(0)
      strFileText = GetText("C:\Users\Yatheesh.Sathyanaray.STDC\Documents1.txt")

        With mailobj
        .To = "yatheesh.satyanarayana@stratogent.com"
        .Subject = "Testmail"
        .Body = strFileText
        .Display
      End With

      'Clear the memory
      Set outobj = Nothing
      Set mailobj = Nothing

    End Sub

    Function GetText(sFile As String) As String
       Dim nSourceFile As Integer, sText As String
       nSourceFile = FreeFile
       'Write the entire file to sText
       Open sFile For Input As #nSourceFile
       sText = Input$(LOF(1), 1)
       Close
       GetText = sText
    End Function
```

Comment: `VBScript` doesn't allow you to define variables as types like `String` so you'll need to drop all the `as Integer` or `as String` statements...

Comment: That entire function `GetText()` will fail, in VBScript if you want to read a file you use the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` of which there are numerous examples on [so].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read from a text file using VBScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/855034/692942)

Answer (score -1):

It works in my machine with your code provide. I've tested it in a Excel file and copy your code as below:

[image]

However, I'm noticed you used a property named "FreeFile", Use without what it seems that.

Comment: It *”works”* because you are using VBA not VBScript they are not the same. They may share similarities but they also have quite stark differences and shouldn’t be used interchangeably.